# Words with plural-only nouns

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Some words are used only with singular countable nouns, others only with plural countable nouns and others only with uncountable nouns

| Category | singular countable | plural countable | uncountable | plural-only |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Examples | car, cat, chair | cars, cats, chairs | air, water, money | trousers, the Middle Ages, binoculars, outskirts, premises, troops (=soldiers, especially in large groups), groceries (=food and other goods sold by a grocer or at a supermarket) |
| one, a, an | OK | NO | NO | ??? |
| every | OK | NO | NO | ??? |
| zero, two, three | NO | OK | NO | ??? |
| many | NO | OK | NO | ??? |
| a large number of | NO | OK | NO | ??? |
| (a) few, fewer, the fewest | NO | OK | NO | ??? |
| much | NO | NO | OK | ??? |

But what about plural-only nouns? What words cannot occur with plural-only nouns? In other words, could you fill in the missing cells in the table?